# Is there an easy way to center a <div> inside another <div> with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar at the top of a page I am developing. I want a certain `<div>` to be centered in the bar (which is another `<div>`). Is there an easy way to do this with CSS? I tried using pixels but that does not work when you resize the window.

I am trying to center it horizontally not vertically.

Update:

The `<div>` that I want centered is one of three `<div>`s in one `<div>`. It is a search bar.

below is an image of what I want and what it is with margin set to auto. (sorry the image does not exactly show where I want the search bar placed. I want it placed a little more to the left (at the center of the nav bar)

[image]

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit. For example, by default the inner DIV's width will be 100% of the parent DIV so centering will be redundant... is there more than one child divs? etc.

Comment: @Chris Bentley ok, I just added more detail.

Comment: @chromedude So are you currently floating the child divs? Do they all Have fixed widths?... How are you currently laying it out?

Comment: @Chris Bentley see the screenshot I just added to the question. The search bar is the div I am talking about. Its sibling <div>s are the three links on the left side and the two links on the right side (each grouping is a <div> the bar is the parent <div>

Comment: The location you have indicated in the screen shot is not centered for any definition of "centered."  I'm not exactly sure where you want it...

Comment: @cdhowie, I meant more centered, but on accident didn't get it exactly centered

Comment: Duplicate of your other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233669/how-to-float-divs-inside-other-divs

Comment: @Grillz I know, I was trying it at a different angle because I wasn't getting satisfactory answers, I guess I should delete the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;` to the inner `<div>`.  See [this example](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html).

Comment: I don't know if you would change your answer based on the image I added. What suggested is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrap { margin:0 auto; width:800px; }
```

If you don't want to set an explicit width you'll have to use an alternate method.

Comment: can we use text-align :center?

Comment: That centers text, not block level elements. Except in quirks mode IE due to a bug, but that's only IE.

Comment: thanks for the explanation got it, i casually uses text-align so many times ...just thought of knowing reality.

Comment: I don't know if you would change your answer based on the image I added. What suggested is not what I want.

Comment: @chromedude - you should have added all this info beforehand. please provide the css.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways to do it, but this simple reduction should get you going...
This won't work on IE6 and below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled</title>
   <style type="text/css">
        #nav {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #nav div {
            display: table-cell;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .menu1 {text-align: left;}
        .menu2 {text-align: right;}
        .site-search {text-align: center;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="nav">

      <div class="menu1">
         MENU ONE
      </div>

      <div class="site-search">
         SEARCH BOX
      </div>

      <div class="menu2">
         MENU TWO
      </div>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll need to reset the text-align of your descendent elements to left or whatever you need.

IF you need IE6 support you could do something along the lines of...

```
<style type="text/css">
   #nav {
      border: 1px red solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
   }

   .menu1 {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      text-align: left;
   }

   .menu2 {
      float: right;
      width: 30%;
      text-align: right;
   }

   .site-search {
      display: inline;
   }
</style>
```

Depending on your situaltion you could use the first example by default and fallback to the second example for IE6 using Conditional Comments..

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<div class="cen">
</div>
</div>
```

and then

```
.cen{
margin:auto;
}
```

This would horizantally center align your div

Comment: I don't know if you would change your answer based on the image I added. What suggested is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Another method which hasn't been mentioned is to use absolute positioning with a negative margin. Works cross-browser too, but you need an explicit width.

```
<div class="parent-container"> <!-- this needs to have position: relative -->
    <div id="search">Search...</div>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS**

```
.parent-container {
    position: relative; // this is so #search is positioned relatively to it's parent
}

#search {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px; // note the explicit width
    left: 50%; // This moves the element 50% to the left
    margin-left: -125px; // This is exactly HALF of the elements width
}
```

If you don't quite understand it, let me know and I'll try add a bit more information.

**Update**
Another way is to use the `table-cell` approach, [as discussed here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Centering_Block_Element#When_you_don.27t_know_the_width).